# Are single quotations necessary in SQL queries? Specifically, Java JDBC queries

Tags: java, mysql

I am using MySQL Workbench as a GUI for my servers.

Looking at some of the queries that Workbench does, it seems to single quotation my database name and the column names, i.e.

```
"INSERT INTO `mydb`.`weather_data`(`dateTime`,`hourlyTemp`,`dewPoint`,`windSpeed`,`relHum`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Now, I am using JDBC (Java) to do an automatic query. The string I use is:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`weather_data`" 
                + "(`dateTime`,`hourlyTemp`,`dewPoint`,`windSpeed`,`relHum`) VALUES" 
                + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

My question is, should I use the single quotations? Should I remove them? Is it necessary?

EDIT second question:

This is my full preparedStatement();

```
private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException{
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`weather_data`" 
                + "(`dateTime`,`hourlyTemp`,`dewPoint`,`windSpeed`,`relHum`) VALUES" 
                + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, "1111111111"); // dateTime
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 12); // hourlyTemp
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 12); // dewPoint
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, 12); //windSpped
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, 12); //relHum
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Record was inserted into mydb weather_data");

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();
        }finally{
            if(preparedStatement!=null){
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(dbConnection!=null){
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the data is not being appended/added/inserted into my DB despite having no connection errors.

Comment: You don't need single quotes. In general 'mydb' will be inherited from connection string and you will be left with only table & columns in queries.

Comment: No, they're not necessary unless your table field has spaces inside (but that would be an odd design to begin with).

Comment: Those aren't single quotes. They are called "backticks" and serve a completely different purpose than single quotes. The backticks are MySQL's version of the ANSI standard double quote `"` for quoting object identifiers. A single quote `'` is used to define a string literal `'foobar'`

Comment: And techincally speaking, they aren't single quotes.  It's a backtick.  **`**  vs **'**  Like double quotes or square brackets in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you - you're right @Andrew and horse

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with anything, but you need a clearBatch after your execute to flush out the batch.

Comment: Where would I be placing the `clearBatch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not required, but very nice to have.  You're letting the parser and any human reading it, what is a table, column, string.  You should continue using them.  Not using them can only hurt you, using them just adds extra bytes to your file.

Comment: *You should continue using them.* this is primarily opinion based, though.

Comment: Do you see any errors in that specific query? For some reason, the data is not being parsed into my db despite having no connection errors.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage if there's any exception, you should log it in your application, edit your post and add the stacktrace of the exception to receive a better and accurate answer.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage everything looks ok. Seems that you're reviewing the changes in a different database.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the table and field names in backticks, but you don't have to.  The advantage of using backticks is that you may use some special characters in your field names (e. g. a comma). (But should anyone really want to do this?)  The disadvantage is that backticks are not part of the ANSI SQL standard.  So using backticks could possibly break your code if you migrate to an other SQL implementation as MSSQL.

**tl;dr:**  Some consider it a good style to use backticks, but you are not required to do this if you do not want to use special characters in your field names.

*Edited:* as @a_horse_with_no_name said in the comments, MySQL is the only major system that supports backticks.

Comment: **No** other DBMS supports backticks (except for MariaDB of course which is a MySQL fork). They are non-standard and I prefer to use the standard syntax for quoting object identifiers using double quotes (`"orders"`) which in fact **is** supported by all other DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, I did not know that (as I don't use backticks ;)). Thanks, I'll add it to my post.

Comment: Sadly enough, MySQL doesn't support double quotes or square brackets.

Comment: @Andrew: MySQL *does* support double quotes when run with "ANSI" mode - and square brackets are just as non-standard as backticks (and should be avoided for the same reasons)